# Listing files on Microsoft Azure Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, glob

I'm working in the Microsoft Azure Databricks. And using the `ls` command, I found out that there is a CSV file present in it (see first screenshot). But when I was trying to pick the CSV file into a list using glob, it's is returning an empty list (see second screenshot).

How can I list the contents of a directory in Databricks?

[image]

[image]

```
%fs 
    ls /FileStore/tables/26AS_report/normalised_consol_file_record_level/part1/customer_pan=AAACD3312M/
```

```py
path = "/FileStore/tables/26AS_report/normalised_consol_file_record_level/part1/customer_pan=AAACD3312M/"
result = glob.glob(path+'/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use standard Python file system functions from the `os.path` or `glob` modules.

Instead, you should use the Databricks file system utility (`dbutils.fs`). See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#file-system-utility-dbutilsfs).

Given your example code, you should do something like:

```py
dbutils.fs.ls(path)
```

or

```py
dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:' + path)
```

This should give a list of files that you may have to filter yourself to only get the `*.csv` files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I'm looping in a for loop and  My task requires reading csv files from certain directory/path and put it in a list and if file is present do further sub-tasks, but the issue is if any one path does not exist/contain csv files it gives exception and stops the process. I want to avoid this expection. Hence I was trying it to contain the csv files using glob. Pls suggest

Comment: Did you check my updated answer? If you do not add "*.csv" to the path, it should not give an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`glob` is a local file-level operation that doesn't know about DBFS.  If you want to use it, then you need to prepend a `/dbfs` to your path:

```py
path = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/26AS_report/....."
```